# Stop youtube video playing on Close of CUSTOM modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, video

Hello awesome Overflowers.

I managed to implement a nice, simple modal that displays a youtube video when a thumbnail img is clicked.
My challenge is that I can't seem to get the video to stop playing after the modal closes.

I have tried many ideas and scripts on here but a lot of them are relative to Bootstrap modals and I can't seem to find a way to add their scripts to my custom modal.

Can anyone see a simple solution that might stop the video playing?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

So far I used:

```
          $jQuery('.modal-content iframe').attr('src', '');
```

to try to replace the scr with nothing so that the video can't play anymore but this doesn't work when I add it to this section of my code:

```
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
          $jQuery('.modal-content iframe').attr('src', '');
    }
  };
```

-- Full JS SCRIPT --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".modalBtn").click(function() {
  // Get the ID name for the modal from the data-attribute
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('toggle-modal'); 
  // Use the ID from associated Modal that matches the attriutes name
  var modal = document.getElementById(id);
  // Get Modal close button
  var closeModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
  // Open Modal
  modal.style.display = "block";
    // Close Modal when clicking anywhere outside of modal
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
          $jQuery('.modal-content iframe').attr('src', '');
    }
  };
  // Close Modal Function
  function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
        $jQuery('.modal-content iframe').attr('src', '');
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= closeModalBtn.length; i += 1) {
    closeModalBtn[i].onclick = closeModal;
  }
});
</script>
```

-- The HTML that triggers it --

```
<div id="MyModal" class="modal">
                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hiddenid" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must get video element,
"html5-main-video" is youtube video class name,so you can use pause stop video in the model close before

```
var video = document.getElementsByClassName("html5-main-video")[0]
video.pause()
```

you can try this code in youtube console,you will see video stop

Comment: Thank you for the info.   Looking at my JS, where can I declare the variable snippet that you wrote? Thank you

Comment: when you close modal   // Close Modal when clicking anywhere outside of modal
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
          var video = document.getElementsByClassName("html5-main-video")[0]
          video.pause()
    }
  };

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't get this to work but thanks anyway

Comment: because yt video is generated after in you click play button,so if you want get video element,you must click this button in begin,you should learn how to use Chrome DevTools to observe how video elements are generated